# Ctrl+a doesn't return all the way back in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I recently updated my prompt to look something like

```
[user@User] ~/wroking/directory (git-branch)
↳
```

using the following code in my `.bashrc`

```
source ~/.local/bin/git-prompt.sh
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE="true"
PS1='\e[0;36m[${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h] \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\e[m\n\e[1;36m⤷\e[m '
```

However when I `ctrl+a` back to the start of input, the cursor (`█`) only moves like so

```
[user@User] ~/wroking/directory (git-branch)
↳ command --option1=foo --option2=bar█
```

`ctrl+a`

```
[user@User] ~/wroking/directory (git-branch)
↳ command -█option1=foo --option2=bar
```

`ctrl+k`

```
[user@User] ~/wroking/directory (git-branch)
↳ command -█
```

`ctrl+e`

```
[user@User] ~/wroking/directory (git-branch)
↳ command -         █
```

If I press `back-space` after `ctrl-a` nothing happens. Nor if I press `left-arrow`.

I can always fix this by clearing the screen, however I find this behaviour really annoying and distracting. Especially since I don't know what is going on. Does anybody know? How do I fix this?

Comment: The color in the prompt seem to be the issue. If I change my `.bashrc` to 
`PS1='[${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h] \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\n⤷ '` than it is fixed. But I like my prompt to have a little darker tone, so I can focus on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap color codes in `\[` and `\]`

```
PS1='\[\e[0;36m\][${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h] \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\[\e[m\]\n\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[m\] '
```

Comment: I couldn't paste that arrow, so I put in `\$`